# How to emulate html_nodes from rvest (from R) with beautifulsoup (or other) in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have this R script that I'm trying to remake in python.

In R I'm using the `rvest` package but I'm struggling to find the equivalent syntax in `bs4`

```
myurllist<-"http://mis.ercot.com/misapp/GetReports.do?reportTypeId=12301&reportTitle=Settlement%20Point%20Prices%20at%20Resource%20Nodes,%20Hubs%20and%20Load%20Zones&showHTMLView=&mimicKey"
mylist<-GET(myurllist)
file_list<-mylist %>% read_html %>% html_nodes(".labelOptional_ind") %>% html_text
url_list<-read_html(mylist) %>% html_nodes("a") %>% html_attr('href')
```

When I run that I get `file_list` which is actual filename whereas the `url_list` is the links to download those.  I'm not sure how to do the same with python.

if I do:

```
page=requests.get(myurllist)
fp= BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
url_list_raw=fp.find_all('a')
url_list=[x['href'] for x in url_list_raw]
```

I can get `url_list` with pretty similar syntax.  I can hack at `url_list_raw` to get a `file_list` if I do this:

```
file_list=[x.parent.parent.parent.find('td').text for x in url_list_raw]
```

Using that triple `parent` feels pretty hacky and like it might brake with a minor change to the site.  Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent version for your second is to continue using a css class selector, as with rvest, within your list comprehension; this will be applied via `select()` method of bs4. You will then need the `.text` property of each node.

```
 file_list = [i.text for i in fp.select('.labelOptional_ind')]
```